# Use static or Dynamic IP based on GPIO Pin

Tags: gpio, networking, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I have a switch on my PI and I want to be able to use a static ip or dynamic ip based on the switches position.

Is it possible to get GPIO pin data in dhcpcd.conf?

Comment: you're dealing with linux, anything is possible

Comment: As jsotola said anything is possible but if you explain what you want to achieve you may get a more helpful suggestion.

Comment: do some research ... figure out how to run a script when a GPIO pin changes state ... then write a script that renames dhcpcd.dynamic to dhcpcd.conf and restarts the network daemon

Answer (score 3):

The Answer to the Question you actually asked is quite simple.

`dhcpcd` is a generic service which is applicable to ANY Linux distribution.
It is **NOT** specific to the Pi, has no knowledge of the Pi hardware, and thus has **NO** code which could interrogate the Pi hardware.

It would be possible to write some code to re-configure `dhcpcd` when a GPIO pin changes state, but you will have to write this yourself.